# write a xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, jupyter

I have a piece of code to write a binary string to a xml file. Since I am using jupyter notebook, I don't understand why there is a number output and what the number stands for?

```
output = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding="UTF-8")
open('outputbook.xml','wb').write(output)
```

And i get `346` as the output of this cell

Comment: Please do not put images of code into a question. It's text - add it to the question **as text**.

Comment: You should be using `with open() as file: file.write()`

Comment: but why I get a number when I run the cell?

Comment: The write function returns None, so you shouldn't get any output

Comment: This is why I get confused. I used to use anaconda prompt to demonstrate but this time we have to use jupyter notebook. I cannot find any explanation about this number

Comment: The docstring in my python says "Write the given buffer to the IO stream.

Returns the number of bytes written, which is always the length of b
in bytes."

Comment: Thank you so much @Goyo I somehow realise this is for the file size as I tried by adding more xml elements. But I was not sure that is Byte or ASCII number etc.